# UWP Page.OnNavigatedFrom() not called when app is terminated

Tags: c#, uwp

I've overridden the `Page.OnNavigatedFrom()` method in a UWP app. The method is called when I navigate to another Page. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom), `Page.OnNavigatedFrom()` is:

> Invoked immediately after the Page is unloaded and is no longer the
>   current source of a parent Frame.

However, when I terminate the app, the Page's `OnNavigatedFrom()` is not called. Shouldn't terminating the app unload the Page?

```
// Not called when app is terminated
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```

### Update

I appreciate the comments. To be more clear, I should have said that I was **closing** the app, not **terminating** the app. (Closing the app first suspends and then terminates the app.) I discovered that putting a call to `Frame.GetNavigationState()` in `OnSuspending()` caused `OnNavigatedFrom()` to be called even when the user closes the app:

```
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
    //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity

    // Triggers currently loaded Page's OnNavigatedFrom
    Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["NavigationState"] =
        frame.GetNavigationState();

    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Comment: `OnNavigatedFrom` will be called when you close the App. Could you please share some more code which shows your navigation logic.

Comment: You cannot terminate a UWP app, you can only suspend it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/suspend-an-app

Comment: The app terminated while the page was the current page. It was never unloaded. The user never navigated away from it. You can have your page save state on suspension if you need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Invoked immediately after the Page is unloaded and is no longer the current source of a parent Frame

I think you misunderstood the document. `OnNavigatedFrom()` method will invoked when page unloaded **and is no longer the current source of frame**.  It is page life cycle only available in the scenario of navigation stack.

But, terminate is the [app life cycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle) concept. and its priority is higher than the page life cycle.

When you terminate uwp app, `OnSuspending` event handler will be invoked, if you want to save page data, you could subscribe this event in page class.